# How to enable access from Cloud Run to BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Trying for **3 hours** already to enable access from Cloud Run to BigQuery.

I have VMs in gcp that access BigQuery, and also my home comuter does access BigQuery with the same code and keys.

Clout Run does access the VMs and Cloud Storage.

How to make Cloud Run be able to access BigQuery as well? Just like the other VMs and my home PC?

Comment: On Cloud Run you don't need a key. You can use the runtime service account (the Cloud Run service identity. By default it's the compute engine default service account that is used.). This identity must have the permission to run a job and to view the data in BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity if it's not that, can you share your code and your error to be able to help your more on it?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the bottom line is that it took me over 3 hours to figure out that I need to select: Route all traffic to the VPC, for it to start working. A very unpleasant experience.